# Iterate over n files?

Tags: shell, imagemagick

I've got something fairly simple I want to do. I want to use `montage` on a directory that contains thousands of images, with very few options, namely:

```
me@home$ montage -size 256x256 DSC01*.JPG.svg output.png
```

...but that's just not good enough, as it only grabs about 100 images at a time; neither is

```
me@home$ montage -size 256x256 *.svg output.png
```

...which grabs all of the images at the same time, as the resulting file is too big to parse.

What I *want to do* is to iterate over something like 100-200 files at a time. I  guess this could be implemented using a for loop (?), but I'm just a bit confused about how to do that. I guess there's probably a clever way to use `find -exec` or `xargs` that I'm not thinking of. I'm using `bash`, but I use `zsh` occasionally.

*So, in conclusion, I'm looking for a one liner that, given 2600 image files, calls montage about 13 or 26 times (once for each 100-200 files), and given n files, can be called a multiple of n times.*

Comment: Are your files all named `DSC0100.JPG.svg` ... `DSC2600.JPG.svg`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `bash` method, using special array features; probably translatable to `zsh` with some modification:

```
image_files=(*.svg) # use your own glob expression
n=200               # number of files per command line; adjust to taste
for ((i=0; i < ${#image_files[@]}; i+=n)); do
        montage -size 256x256 "${image_files[@]:i:n}" output-"$i".png
done
```

Comment: i found this bit of bash scripting is also very extensible. i just used it to move some files around (16 files per directory) and it worked on the first try, which was a bit of a surprise. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use xargs for that; unfortunately, it is not possibly to combine -I (for instering into the middle of a command line) and -L (for limiting the number of files for a single call to the executable). Therefore, I created this command line as an example (but beware of special characters in file names, they are not supported):

```
 ls . | \
   xargs -n 100 echo | \
   (a=1; 
    while read args; do 
     echo montage -size 256x256 $args output-$a.png;
     a=$((a+1)); 
    done
   )
```

Remove the `echo` if you want to really execute the command.

Caveats:

- **filenames may not contain spaces or other special characters**
- the last montage line might have less than 100 files in it

**Update:**

This is the corresponding for loop, which (I hope) solves the problem with spaces in file names:

```
a=0
b=0
lst=
for f in *; do 
  a=$((a+1))
  lst="$lst '$f'"
  if test $a -ge 100; then 
    eval echo montage --args $lst target-$b.png
    b=$((b+1))
    a=0
    lst=
  fi 
done
```

**Update 2:** A python solution, which should be immune to special characters in file names

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# iterate.py

"""Usage: 
%prog <number per call> <file pattern> <command prefix> -- <command postfix>
e.g.  %prog 100 "DSC01*.jpg.svg" montage -size 256x256 -- output-%i.png """

import sys,subprocess,glob,os

if len(sys.argv) < 5: 
  print __doc__.replace("%prog", os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
  sys.exit(1)

def chunks(l, n): 
  for i in xrange(0, len(l), n): yield l[i:i+n]

num, pattern, args = int(sys.argv[1]), sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3:]
files, idx = glob.glob(pattern), args.index("--")
before, after = args[0:idx], args[idx+1:]

for idx,chunk in enumerate(chunks(files,num)):
  subprocess.call( before + chunk + [s.replace("%i",str(idx)) for s in after] )
```

Comment: If you are going to recommend using `ls` in a pipe to parse its output, you should also [warn about the many dangers of doing so](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) prominently, and at the beginning to make sure people see it.

Comment: @jw013 +1 Yes, that's definitely a concern. However, his posting let me assume that he was using photos directly imported from a digital camera, which do not contain any special characters. How would you suggest to tackle that problem?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the file names are relatively benign (hence no downvote).  However the OP hasn't really specified what they look like beyond `*.svg` (which is why I posted a comment on the question asking).  In the most general case where you need to handle all file names, you'd have to resort to shell globbing and arrays or `find -print0 | xargs -0` constructs.  See my [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42904/9537) for an example of the former.

Comment: @jw013 Your answer is really nice! I never took the effort to learn how arrays work in bash. Maybe I should.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel -N200 montage -size 256x256 {} output{#}.png ::: *.svg
```

It is of course safe for files with special characters (as you can normally expect of GNU Parallel).

**Minimal installation**

If you just need parallel and do not have 'make' installed (maybe the
system is old or Microsoft Windows):

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
mv parallel sem dir-in-your-$PATH/bin/
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1 or at
http://tinyogg.com/watch/TORaR/ and http://tinyogg.com/watch/hfxKj/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using xargs that's safe for any filename, but requires a temporary file to store the count.  Adjust the '-n 100' to adjust how many files per montage.  You can also swap the "printf" with a "find -print0", but make sure it doesn't find "count.temp".

```
echo 1 >count.temp
printf "%s\0" *.svg | xargs -0 -n 100 sh -c '
    a=`cat count.temp`
    montage --blah "$@" output-"$a".png
    let a=a+1
    echo "$a" >count.temp
    '
rm count.temp
```